# When copy address for wget other files download

Tags: wget

I was given a shared directory with files on owncloud. To download only some of them to my directory on a remote server, I right-click on a file name, copy the link address and use

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O 1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz https://url/index.php/s/download?path=%2F&files=1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

instead of downloading just that one file, it tries to download all the files from the directory and crashes because of memory shortage. How do I download files separately in this case?

P.S.: if I just click on the filename on a web browser, it downloads the exact file I need. So wget should download just that file, right? Why does it load all the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always quote the arguments with special characters

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O 1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz 'https://url/index.php/s/download?path=%2F&files=1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz'
```

Comment: I want to stress that it's necessary to use single straight marks, `'`, not double quotation marks `"` or backticks or anything. The single quotations marks are the ones that stop the shell from doing any interpretation in the string.